# Testing a scroll on an Animated.ScrollView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently writing tests for a component I implemented using the `react-test-renderer` and an issue I've come across is trying to test the callback function that is called when I scroll on my `Animated.ScrollView`.

Here's a succint version of what I currently have with generic naming:

Component

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, MyComponentState> {

    public componentWillMount() {
        this.index = 0;
        this.routeSelectionAnimation = new Animated.Value(0);
    }


    public componentDidMount() {
        this.routeSelectionAnimation.addListener(({ value }) => {
            // some work is done before the following line
            // the function I want to test is being called
            this.props.onIndexUpdate(index);
        });
    }

    public render() {
        const scrollAnimation = Animated.event(
            [{
                nativeEvent: {
                    contentOffset: {
                            x: this.routeSelectionAnimation,
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
            { useNativeDriver: true },
        );

        // * more processing *

        return (
            <Animated.ScrollView
              horizontal={true}
              scrollEventThrottle={1}
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              snapToInterval={...}
              pagingEnabled={true}
              onScroll={scrollAnimation} // what matters is this
              style={styles.scrollView}
            >
                {other components}
            </Animated.ScrollView>
        );
    }
```

This works correctly on the device, the function passed by props `onIndexUpdate(int)` is called when the ScrollView scrolls.

I would like to test this behaviour, however I can't seem to simulate the scroll on the ScrollView. I was thinking of doing something like:

```
const props = {
    onIndexUpdate: jest.fn(),
};

const getTestInstance = () => {
    return TestRenderer.create(
        <MyComponent onIndexUpdate={props.onIndexUpdate} />
    ).root;
};

describe("Animated.ScrollView", () => {
    it("calls function", () => {
        const instance = getTestInstance();
        const scrollView = instance.findByType(Animated.ScrollView);
        scrollView.instance.scrollToEnd({animated: false});

        expect(props.onIndexUpdate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
    });
});
```

But it does not work. What I get as a result is `TypeError: scrollView.instance.scrollToEnd is not a function` which clearly shows I'm looking at this wrong...

I'd greatly appreciate input on how to fix this or approach the testing in a more correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You missed out a print statement, thats why it wont work. You should have put:

```
print scrollView.instance.scrollToEnd({animated: false});
```